# Sharing data with custom list of intent display an Android System

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter, share, social-networking

I try to share some data only via facebook, twitter and g+, so I create a custom list of intent and I can send some text, everything works fine.
But I got a display problem with twitter see below 
[image]

You can see this Systeme Android and if i click on it, i got this :
[image]

See the code :

In this first function I just put the package I would like to use

```
private List<String> getShareApplication(){
    List<String> mList=new ArrayList<>();
    mList.add("com.facebook.katana");
    mList.add("com.google.android.apps.plus");
    mList.add("com.twitter.android");
    return mList;
}
```

And in this one I'm using the list just above, I look in the loop if the package exist on my phone, I create an Intent call targetedShare with an ACTION_SEND and put some text inside it, and finally add it to the targetedShareIntents list

```
 private void Share(List<String> PackageName) {
            List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<>();
            Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("text/plain");
            List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
            if (!resInfo.isEmpty()){
                for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
                    Intent targetedShare = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    if (PackageName.contains(info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase())) {
                        targetedShare.setType("text/plain");
                        targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, String.valueOf(urlJson));
                        targetedShare.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase());
                        targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShare);
                    }
                }
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Share");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[targetedShareIntents.size()]));
                startActivity(chooserIntent);
            }
        }
    }
```

I try to use some other code found on stackOverflow, and I try with other device and I try to use some other twitter package name like :

com.twitter.android.composer.ComposerActivity

com.twitter.android.DMActivity

com.twitter.android.PostActivity

etc...

but I still got this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution if anybody have this issue, you need to add twitter separately in the Intent list with this function :

```
public Intent findTwitterClient() {
    final String[] twitterApps = {
            "com.twitter.android",
            "com.twidroid",
            "com.handmark.tweetcaster",
            "com.thedeck.android" };
    Intent tweetIntent = new Intent();
    tweetIntent.setType("text/plain");
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
            tweetIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    for (int i = 0; i < twitterApps.length; i++) {
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : list) {
            String p = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            if (p != null && p.startsWith(twitterApps[i])) {
                tweetIntent.setPackage(p);
                return tweetIntent;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And you can use it like this :
targetedShareIntents.add(findTwitterClient());